I am getting issue in "ethers.utils.parseEther("1");"?
Please follow these steps to see my problem
You need to type the following command in terminal to install ethers.js

npm install --save ethers

//create a hardhat project by using these commands

mkdir lesson1
cd lesson1
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev hardhat 
npx hardhat //Create a project that uses Typescript

The default repo comes with a Lock.sol contract. Now, compile the contract.
It will successfully compile.
Now, create a "scripts" folder in "lesson1" folder and again create a file named "deploy.ts" in "scripts" folder and paste this code.

async function main() {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const ONE_YEAR_IN_SECS = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + ONE_YEAR_IN_SECS;

  const lockedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

  const Lock = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
  const lock = await Lock.deploy(unlockTime, { value: lockedAmount });

  await lock.deployed();

  console.log(`Lock with 1 ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${lock.address}`);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});```

After pasting this code, I am getting error in "ethers.utils.parseEther("1");" line that "Property 'utils' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/workspace/Beginning-Javascript/lesson1/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/ethers") & HardhatEthersHelpers""

Please help me by fixing this.

I tried converting whole project from typescript to javascript but got another problem.

